# Applications of broadcast packets?

Tags: network-programming, broadcast, arp

Like arp ( to resolve destination), are there any other application where we are using broadcast packet messages.

If possible give some reference links too.

Answer (score 0):

The types of broadcasting uses on TCP/IP:

```
ARP on IP
DHCP on IP
Routing table updates. Broadcasts sent by routers with routing table updates to other routers.
```

Ref : http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/networking/guide/netbroadcasting.html

Answer (score 0):

One appication of broadcast frames is actually in the V2X (Vehicle-to-everything) communications in vehicular networks, for which 802.11 based protocols have been created (for instance the 802.11p amendment to the 802.11-2016 standard). Also other non-IP higher layer protocols exist for such purposes, such as WSMP (WAVE short message protocol).

Nodes (i.e. vehicles) are continuosly moving, and broadcasting information can be the solution, for instance, to share information between vehicles about their position and velocity, or to flood an information such an enountered patch of ice on the road or an accident to all the surrounding vehicles on a certain channel.

The WSMP protocol also foresees the so-called "Wave Service Advertisements" (WSA), which are packets containing information about application services provided by the sender: if I understood correctly, they are typically broadcasted by vehicles or by infrastructure nodes.

There would be actually a lot of words to spend talking about this field, which, in any case, lies a lot on broadcasting data.

As source I actually used the IEEE 802.11-2016 and IEEE 1609.x (in particular IEEE 1609.3) protocols, which unfortunately I'm not able to share here right now. If you look for publications about V2X protocols, though, I'm sure you will find much more about this world.